# find $f$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2})=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t)dt$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V=P_2(X)$ with inner product $<f,g>=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t) \ dt$. 
Find $f \in V$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2})=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t) \ dt$ for every $g \in V$.

I tried considering $g(t)=at^2+bt+c$ to find something about $f $ but that didn't work.

I tried to somehow use the orthogonal basis but I don't know how.

Any hint? I am stuck.

Comment: Is g also in $V$?

Comment: Are we allowed to pick both $f$ and $g$? Then it is easy, pick both of them constant equal to $1$.

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake, now I fixed it

Comment: That's only one case, you didn't prove that there are  not other solutions.

Comment: Pick $f=0$. That works.

Comment: Well, yes, because that is not what you ask. You might want to write then "Find all $f$..."

Comment: I am sorry the problem in my language doesn't say that, but it is implied, and I had a problem translating sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to sound harsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $f=0$ is a solution.

Assume $f$ is a solution. Picking $g=0$, we get $f(1/2)= \langle f, 0 \rangle =0$. However, picking $ g=f$ yields
$$ 0=f(1/2)= \langle f, f\rangle.$$
Thus, $f=0$.

This implies that the zero function is the unique solution in our space.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(t) \equiv f(t) \equiv 1.$$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and forgot to add that we need this property for every $g \in V$